# PHP, how to convert date in string in format dd-mm-YYYY to date in string in format YYYY-mm-dd?

Tags: php, date, datetime-format

i have a string variable name `$mydate` which means `10 january 2014`

```
$mydate="10-01-2014";
```

i want to convert it to string variable also to be '2014-01-10'

hi Half Crazed,
i have put ur solution like this:

```
foreach($report_data['summary'] as $key=>$row) {

        $substrdate=substr($row['payment_type'],-16); //i have see the result is 10-01-2014

        $originalDate = '10-01-2014';
        try {
          $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $originalDate);
          //echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
        } catch(Exception $e) {
          die("Error converting date. Exception caught: " . $e->getMessage());
        }



        $summary_data_row[] = array('data'=>'<span style="color:'.$color.'">'.$date->format('Y-m-d').'</span>', 'align'=>'right');
        $summary_data_row[] = array('data'=>'<span style="color:'.$color.'">'.$row['comment'].'</span>', 'align'=>'right');
   }//end of foreach
```

it runs well until  i replace variable $originalDate with $substrdate which has same value -> '10-01-2014' why it become not work anymore?

Comment: `echo date('Y-m-d')` aj mbak. Bs dipisah pake `-`, `|`, `/` dll.

Comment: Skrg kendala ny apa stlh pk `$substrdate ` ? ga keluar atau formatnya salah ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) to read in the date and convert it to a new format.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j F Y', '10 january 2014');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP's `DateTime` object, you can use the method `createFromFormat`:

`$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '10-01-2014');`

Then you can convert it via:

`echo $date->format('Y-m-d');`

Of course, you should wrap this all in a `try` `catch` block:

```
$originalDate = '10-01-2014';
try {
  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $originalDate);
  echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
} catch(Exception $e) {
  die("Error converting date. Exception caught: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: hi Half Crazed. thanks for respond. please see my edited post above..